# IOS 7 native keyboard not appering when using xcode 4.5?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

When i run the xcode4.5 build of my project on ios7 then keyboard appearing is not ios native keyboard which is native to ios7 but it is showing the previous greyish keyboard but alertview is working fine.

**I can move to xcode 5 but there is many UI issue when i switch to xcode 5.**

Reset of things are working fine with xcode 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch to Xcode 5 for the keyboard. There is not other way I know of. Also the users will like your app more if it has the iOS 7 features.

Comment: is there any way to update your app in xcode5 easily because when i switch to it the whole view shuffled. for ex- some button go upward

Comment: @rohitjindal Are you using Auto-Layout in your app?

Answer (score -1):

As already mentioned, you need to move to Xcode 5. As you've noticed, the alertViews (and actionSheets) will be iOS-7-ified automatically, though.